# How to add class on page load using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Hi Friends i have created a dynamic class on click on a tag, but that class is not working on while referesh page. can any one suggest me answer.

**SCRIPT**

```
app.controller("con",function($scope){

$scope.yellowClass = function(){
    $scope.class = "yellow";

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the class someplace if you want to keep it after the refresh. `localStorage` sounds like the way to go. On your app init, you'd read the local storage value and set it to `$scope.class` (or use a default if none is set in the storage).

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Comment: i can't use local storage @Shomz

Comment: Why? Use a cookie then. You need to store it someplace.

Comment: Is there any way using angular?

Comment: using current URL location how can i add class @Shomz

Comment: Use `window.location.hash` then. But that's not `using angular`, whatever that meant.